# Deep Copy of Cons instance of Java List interface

Tags: java, list, immutability

I am implementing a immutable List interface in java, a Cons class, essentially a list of lists ie; Cons(1,2,3)= Cons(1,Cons(2,Cons(3,null)))

I am trying to create a deepcopy of a cons but have had no success

Below is the class constructor methods and intialization:

```
public final class Cons<T> implements List<T> {

  private final T head;
  private List<T> tail; // non-final because of take and join

  Cons(T head, List<T> tail) {
    this.head = head;
    this.tail = tail;
  }
```

Below is the current Copy class:

```
    public Cons<T> copy(Cons<T> tocopy) {
      Cons<T> test=  new Cons<T>(this.head,this.tail);
      return test;
    }
}
```

Below is how its being called, I have confirmed this is simple a shallow copy or refrence to this by appending a value and comparing the copy to this:

```
public List<T> join(List<T> other) {

      Cons<T> cp= copy(this);
      if(other instanceof Nil){
          return cp;
      }
      Cons<T> ptr= (Cons<T>) other;

      for(; ptr instanceof Cons;ptr= (Cons<T>) ptr.tail){
          if(!(ptr.tail instanceof Cons)){
              cp.append(ptr.head);
              break;
          }
          else{
              cp.append(ptr.head);
          }
      }
      return cp;
  }
```

In addition I have tried Cons copy = cons(this.head, this.tail),

Comment: What is the point of copying an immutable object?

Comment: When preforming operations on the list for instance join, they must return a copied join of the original object to not actually change the immutable object.

Comment: An immutable object cannot be changed. That is the definition of an immutable object.

Comment: There is no general way to create a deep copy of a list in java since [`Cloneable` is  considered broken (`artima.com`)](https://www.artima.com/articles/josh-bloch-on-design). We can only implement deep-copying for specific classes.

Comment: Ok, good to know, I am new to java mainly have expierence with C and python. For deepy copying this specific Cons class, how should I go about it. I guess thats what I am really asking. Aside from the methods I tried above, I also tried a copy constructor.

Comment: Is your current `copy()` method supposed to implement a deep copy?  Because it looks like it's not.  So only `join()` performs a deep copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you made `tail` non-final when you said you are making an *immutable* cons list. Also ,`tail` is of type `List` (`java.util.List`?) when it should be of a type that is either `Cons` or `Nil`.

Let's fix those problems by using a sealed interface `ConsList<T>`, which `Cons<T>` and `Nil<T>` implement. We also make `Cons<T>` and `Nil<T>` *records* so that they are immutable.

```
sealed interface ConsList<T> permits Cons, Nil {}
record Cons<T>(T head, ConsList<T> tail) implements ConsList<T> { }
record Nil<T>() implements ConsList<T> {}
```

Now `copy` can be implemented like this:

```
static <T> ConsList<T> copy(ConsList<T> list) {
    Deque<T> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    ConsList<T> temp = list;
    while (temp instanceof Cons<T> cons) {
        stack.push(cons.head());
        temp = cons.tail();
    }
    temp = new Nil<>();
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        temp = new Cons<>(stack.pop(), temp);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

This could also be done with recursion, but unlike functional languages like Haskell, Java doesn't have much optimisations for recursive code like that, so I don't recommend that. The stack would likely overflow for slightly larger lists.

What you will realise though, is that you don't actually need a `copy` method like this. In your `join` method, the only reason why you make a deep copy is because you call `cp.append` later on. Though you did not show the implementation, I can only assume it mutates `cp` in some way. That is not something an *immutable* data type should do.

Instead, you should implement `join` by collecting the elements of each list into a stack, and then making a joined list by popping from the stack.

```
// in ConsList<T> interface
default ConsList<T> join(ConsList<T> other) {
    Deque<T> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();

    // push "this"
    ConsList<T> temp = this;
    while (temp instanceof Cons<T> cons) {
        stack.push(cons.head());
        temp = cons.tail();
    }

    // push other
    temp = other;
    while (temp instanceof Cons<T> cons) {
        stack.push(cons.head());
        temp = cons.tail();
    }

    // pop everything from the stack and make a new ConsList<T>
    temp = new Nil<>();
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        temp = new Cons<>(stack.pop(), temp);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

You can also write this with recursion which would make the code look a lot "nicer", but again, I don't recommend doing so. That said, the code duplication can be slightly refactored:

```
default ConsList<T> join(ConsList<T> other) {
    Deque<T> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    toStack(this, stack);
    toStack(other, stack);
    return fromStack(stack);
}

static <T> void toStack(ConsList<T> list, Deque<T> stack) {
    ConsList<T> temp = list;
    while (temp instanceof Cons<T> cons) {
        stack.push(cons.head());
        temp = cons.tail();
    }
}

static <T> ConsList<T> fromStack(Deque<T> stack) {
    ConsList<T> temp = new Nil<>();
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        temp = new Cons<>(stack.pop(), temp);
    }
    return temp;
}
```